# Meaning of "yeeucch" and "uurgghh"

Tags: meaning

I have read a story and do not understand the meaning of words "Yeeucch" and "Uurgghh" in the context "*But if one comes in the house, especially if it's one of those really big spiders with furry legs and little red eyes, then I go 'Yeeucch' and I try to get rid of it"* and "*When my friend sees a spider, she doesn't just go 'Uurgghh!' or run away or ask someone else to get rid of the horrible creepy-crawly"*. So, could anyone tell me what they mean? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a sidenote, the reader should know your question is about just by reading the title. Though not explicitly disallowed, asking for permission to post is unnecessary.

Comment: Have you *read* the sentences you just posted? Because what they do is actually explain quite well what these words mean. Exclamations of disgust. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yeuch https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/urgh

Answer (score 2):

They are just (exaggerated) representations of the sounds of disgust people make when they see something they don't like.

See the second definition of [yuck](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yuck) (not all possible spellings will be in the dictionary).